# Django models.IntegerField choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django admin page, I have a dropdown field (Teachers Name) that fills from Database when the page loads. But when I want to Save something, the Teacher's dropdown field has an error. I need to TecherID.

My model.py:

```
class classes_info(models.Model):
    ClassName = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Class name")
    On = "On"
    Off = "Off"
    Status_CHOICES = [
        (On, 'On'),
        (Off, 'Off'),
    ]
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Status_CHOICES, default=On)
    Teacher_CHOICES = [
        (0, '-------'),
    ]
    TeacherID = models.IntegerField(max_length=200, choices=Teacher_CHOICES)
```

And My Admin.py:

```
class classes_info_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ClassName')

    def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "TeacherID":
            Teachers_Info = personal_info.objects.values('id', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'images').filter(Type='Teacher', Status='On')
            Teachers_List = [(0, '-------')]
            if len(Teachers_Info) != 0:
                for x in list(Teachers_Info):
                    y = (x['id']), x['FirstName'] + " " + x['MiddleName'] + " " + x['LastName'])
                    Teachers_List.append(y)
            kwargs['choices'] = Teachers_List
        return super(classes_info_Admin, self).formfield_for_choice_field(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Teacher information is loaded from the database:

[image]

When I want to save information, my error in TeacherID field is: "Select a valid choice. 34 is not one of the available choices."

[image]

I have a problem and I don't know what's my problem. Please Help me.
Thanks.

I changed models to CharField:

```
TeacherID = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=Teacher_CHOICES)
```

And also, I changed Datatype in the Database. From BIGINT to LONGTEXT

Answer (score 1):

Your choice is validated by the model, and since that only has `0` as option, it is rejected.

But it is *not* a good idea to define choices which are derived from (another) model. You can work with a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) instead:

```
class StatusBase(models.Model):
    On = "On"
    Off = "Off"
    Status_CHOICES = [
        (On, 'On'),
        (Off, 'Off'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Status_CHOICES, default=On)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Person(StatusBase, models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    # …


class Class(StatusBase, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Class name')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, limit_choices_to={'type': 'Teacher', 'status': 'On'}
    )
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`class_info`</s> to `Class`.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `…Info` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`person_info`</s> to `Person`.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `name` instead of <s>`Name`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally model fields have no prefix with the name of the model. This makes
> queries longer to read, and often want uses inheritance of (abstract) models to
> inherit fields, so using a prefix would make it less reusable. Therefore it
> might be better to rename your field <s>`class_name`</s> to `name`.